# How can I get the column id or the id of the currently focused cell in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I would like to get the id of the currently focused cell(id of the input element of that cell) in jqgrid.I tried getCell method and beforeCelledit method, but all of them expects iCol as a user given parameter.In fact, I want the iCol value to be returned when user focuses on a particular cell of a row. Please help me.

Thanks,
Poorna.

Comment: Do you use [cell editing mode](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing) and want to know which row and cell in editing now?

Comment: Yeah Oleg.I use cell editing mode and want to know which is the currently editing cell

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onCellSelect` method in order to get the current cell and its information by the colModel.

Code:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: ["Id", "Name"],
    colModel: [{
        name: "id",
        index: "id",
        sorttype: "int"
    }, {
        name: "name",
        index: "name"
    }],
    caption: "Viz Test",
    pager: '#pager',
    search: true,
    data: myData,
    onCellSelect: function (row, col, content, event) {
        var cm = jQuery("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
        alert(cm[col].name);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1pt5wnkw/

Comment: Thanks Irvin.I will try this

Comment: I tried it.This is just returning the value in object format.The column name is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Cell editing set two jqGrid options `iCol` and `iRow` additionally to `selrow`. The parameter `selrow` hold the rowid of editing cell, `iRow` hold the index of row and `iCol` hold the column number. So you can use the following

```
// get the reference to object with all parameters of jqGrid
var p = $("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam");

alert("rowid=" + p.selrow +
    ", iRow=" + p.iRow +
    ", iCol=" + p.iCol);
```

By the way, the parameters will be set not only for editable columns. If cell editing is enables and the clicked cell (or the column) is not editable then the cell will be selected, but `selrow`, `iRow` and `iCol` will be still set.

Comment: Hi Oleg, I tried this.All the columns are editable.I tried adding this code oncellSelect as well as onedit function.But, the values are undefined.Also, my cellSelect function seems to work only on first column.When I click the next columns the cellSelect function is not fired.

Comment: @PoornaMurali: Where is your test code? Where you place it? (in some callback or ...) I can't help you to fix the code if I don't see it.

Comment: @PoornaMurali: You can get some demo like http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/qzxwfquq/2/, modify it, save and post me the URL.

Comment: Hi Oleg.I am able to see the column names when I tried the same in the demo that you shared.Now, I am a bit confused about cellEditing Mode.I am using onCellselect and OnselectRow functions .Is nt it the cellEditing mode? or is it a different module as such?

Comment: @PoornaMurali: Why you continue *to explain what you do* in your code instead of posting the code itself? You write about your code only what *you* find important, but if you can't explain some effects, then it means that you don't have full understanding how jqGrid want. I can help you only if I see what you do. Moreover JavaScript is case sensitive. Why you write about `onCellselect` and `OnselectRow` instead of `onCellSelect` and `onSelectRow`? Would you like to be named as PoOrna? Please try be exact.

Comment: Oleg,I got what I want!!! No more explanations.And, you don't have to bother about how I like to be named.

Comment: @PoornaMurali: It's a good news! What was the reason? Do you use now `iRow` and `iCol` parameters like I suggested? About the names, sorry, I want just remark that one have to be carefully in all names which one use.